# ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Module `scrapy.conf` is deprecated, use `crawler.settings` attribute instead

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using scrapy 1.5 and am programmatically trying to run a scrapy crawler process through a python script. As a part of this, I need to import the crawler settings and override some of its parameters.

I found this import statement does what I need:

```
from scrapy.conf import settings
```

The problem is, this works, but also produces the following deprecation warning:

```
ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Module `scrapy.conf` is deprecated, use `crawler.settings` attribute instead
```

So I'm guessing this is for some older version. Following the warning, I tried to access `scrapy.crawler.settings`, but this does not exist (or, I couldn't find it after some searching).

How can I resolve this warning?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is only mentioned in passing, but I found the right way to do this in the [official documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script).

You can use `get_project_settings` to get a `Settings` instance with the project settings:

```
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
SETTINGS = get_project_settings() 

SETTINGS
# {'AJAXCRAWL_ENABLED': False, 'AUTOTHROTTLE_DEBUG': False, ...'USER_AGENT': 'Scrapy/1.5.0 (+https://scrapy.org)'}
```

You can then modify this as needed before passing it to the `CrawlerProcess`.